# Using Xargs max-procs with multiple arguments from a file

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, xargs

I have a script that is getting me the results I want. I want to improve the performance of the script.

My script takes argument from file `file1.txt`.

The contents are below:

```
table1
table2
table3
and so on
```

Now when I use the `while`  statement like below the script runs in sequential order.

`while` statement is below:

```
while IFS=',' read -r a; do import.sh "$a"; done <  file1.txt
```

Now when I use the `xargs` `max-procs` utility in bash then the scripts run in parallel based on no of max-procs.

`xargs` statement is below:

```
xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 sh import.sh <  file1.txt
```

Now I have another script

This script takes arguments from file `file2.txt`.

The contents are below:

```
table1,db1
table2,db2
table3,db3
and so on
```

when I use the `while` statement the script performs fine.

```
while IFS=',' read -r a b; do test.sh "$a" "$b"; done <  file2.txt
```

But when I use teh `xargs` statement then the script gives me `usage` error.

`xargs` statement is below.

```
xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 sh test.sh <  file2.txt
```

The `error` statement is below:

```
Usage : test.sh input_file
```

Why is this happening?

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You can easily debug this issue by adding an `echo` to your command: `xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 echo sh test.sh <  file2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second script, `test.sh`, expects two arguments, but `xargs` is feeding it only one (one word, in this case the complete line). You can fix it by first converting commas `,` to newlines (with a simple `sed` script) and then passing two arguments (now two lines) per call to `test.sh` (with `-n2`):

```
sed s/,/\\n/g file2.txt | xargs --max-procs 10 -n2 sh test.sh
```

Note that `xargs` supports a custom delimiter via `-d` option, and you could use it in case each line in `file2.txt` were ending with `,` (but then you should probably strip a newline prefixed to each first field).