# Decrease the number of calls

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix, arraylist

`I have arraylist of filenames (java) and I want to delete these files using rm`

```
  for(String check: checks){ 
here I am removing each file using rm 
 }
```

but it is time consuming can I do batching using xargs or something else which can help to delete files faster.

Comment: Why don't you delete them with Java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--

Comment: Will it be faster than ( 'rm' in for loop ) because delete also takes one file i guess. Is there any way to batch and delete

Comment: rm can take multiple file arguments, if you insist on doing it that way, just pass a group of file names to the command.  Create a buffer, fill the buffer with 10 or so file names at a time, send that to rm, then clear the buffer and repeat.  After the loop, if there's data in the buffer, send that to rm

Comment: It will be faster because it doesn't have to spawn a shell and an rm process for each file. Have you investigated using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?

Comment: @leoHernandez The time spent running `rm` is about 99.9% process creation and 0.1% file deletion, so you will see a massive speedup if you delete with Java to avoid process creation. There is no "batch deletion": the files are still deleted one by one in a loop, the savings come entirely from creating fewer processes. If you have a SSD you may additionally consider parallelizing though.

Comment: You can use `xargs` to [run processes in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064054/using-xargs-max-procs-with-multiple-arguments-from-a-file)

Comment: ... and `xargs` could also help in reducing the number of processes launched, even if they aren't paralelized.  Though deleting via Java is probably still at least as fast.

Comment: `checks.stream().map(Path::of).foreach(Files::delete);`

Comment: @Shawn Won’t work, because Files.delete throws an exception, which means it doesn’t qualify as a Consumer.

Comment: Thanks alot I got a better over view of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `rm`.  Use Java.

As others have pointed out, spawning a process is much slower than doing it in your program.  Also, it’s just bad design to use a system command for something that can be done in code.

And finally, by using [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)), you gain platform independence.  Your code is now write once, run anywhere!

Here’s what your loop would look like:

```
for (String check : checks) {
    Files.delete(Path.of(check));
}
```

This is essentially the same as what `rm` would do anyway.